# Lowercase user-commands?

Tags: command, quit, user-commands

After years of torture, my trusty rusty keyboard is finally waning its power—it now seems to believe that I'm jitter-clicking whenever I press <kbd>q</kbd>. Before getting a new one, I would like to ask if there is a way to gracefully exit vim with `:qqqqq` or `:wqqq` (or dare I dream, `:qqqqqq!` and `:wqqqqa`). I know custom commands cannot begin with a lowercase letter, for future expansion reasons; but genuinely, I highly doubt that dear Bram would be interested in creating a new command called `qqqqq` so we should be in the clear. Therefore, any trickeries to bypass that? If there's no magic, I suppose I'll just turn to use `ZZ`.

Comment: See `:help :cabbrev`.

Comment: @romainl I don’t think it is possible to pass a regex into cabbrev, something like `cabbrev wq+a wqa`…

Comment: It's not. Just make as many abbreviations as needed while you are waiting for your new keyboard to be delivered.

Comment: Make use of the [cmdalias plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746) or [vimalias plugin](https://github.com/Konfekt/vim-alias)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose I agree with @romainl you need a new keyboard.

Here is my proposition:

```
function! CorrectCommand()
  if getcmdtype() != ':'
    return "\<CR>"
  endif

  if matchstr(getcmdline(), '^w\=q\+!\=') == ''
    return "\<CR>"
  endif

  let l:cmdline = getcmdline()

  " Parse the cmd line
  let l:newcmdline = l:cmdline
  let l:good = v:true
  if matchstr(l:cmdline, 'qq\+!\=') != ''
    let l:newcmdline = substitute(l:cmdline, 'q\+', 'q', 'g')
    let l:good = v:false
  endif

  if l:good
    return "\<CR>"
  else
    return "\<C-u>" . l:newcmdline
  endif

endfunction
cnoremap <expr> <CR> CorrectCommand()
```

In case your command match `:w\=q\+!\=` (an optional `w` followed by `qqq` followed by an optional `!`) the mapping will propose a correction when you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you like the correction you can just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> once more and the command will be executed.